# Slick2D Mouse event propagation

Tags: slick2d

I am implementing a small game ( Basic game state) and I have a hard time with the buttons navigation.
I have a class Menu which contains 3 button: Play, How To Play and Exit.
For example when I click How To Play button it redirects me to the How To Play class. 
In How To Play class I have just a button: Back which is suppose to redirect me back to the Menu class. 
Everything is working but when I click the back button it exit the game, and this is because it has the same coordinates as the Exit button from Menu.
How can I stop the propagation?
My code is like:

```
Main Class:

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{ // update the images on screen to create image movement illusion
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    mouseX = Mouse.getX();
    mouseY = gc.getHeight()-Mouse.getY();
    position = "*xpos: "+mouseX+" ypos:"+mouseY;
    buttonsListener(input, sbg);
}
public void buttonsListener(Input input, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException
{

    if((mouseX>130&&mouseX<477)&&(mouseY>308&&mouseY<377))//play button
        if(input.isMouseButtonDown(0))
            sbg.enterState(1);  

    if((mouseX>130&&mouseX<477)&&(mouseY>408&&mouseY<477))//how to play button
        if(input.isMouseButtonDown(0))
            sbg.enterState(2);

    if((mouseX>130&&mouseX<477)&&(mouseY>508&&mouseY<577))//exit button
        if(input.isMouseButtonDown(0))
            System.exit(0);
}
```

And:

```
HowToPlay Class: 

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    mouseX = Mouse.getX();
    mouseY = gc.getHeight()-Mouse.getY();

    if((mouseX>130&&mouseX<477)&&(mouseY>508&&mouseY<577))//back button
        if(input.isMouseButtonDown(0))
            sbg.enterState(0);
}
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, so for any of you having the same problem, you can simply overwrite the mousePressed method, like(in my case):

```
Main class:
public void mousePressed(int button, int x, int y) { // check if the buttons are pressed
       if((x>130&&x<477)&&(y>308&&y<377))
            if(button==0)
                sbg.enterState(1);  
        if((x>130&&x<477)&&(y>408&&y<477))
            if(button==0)
                sbg.enterState(2);
        if((x>130&&x<477)&&(y>508&&y<577))
            if(button==0)
                System.exit(0);
    }
```

And

```
Howtoplay class:
public void mousePressed(int button, int x, int y) { // check if the buttons are pressed
    if( ( x > 130 && x < 477 ) && ( y > 508 && y < 577 ) )
        if(button==0)
            sbg.enterState(0);
}
```

And it will not propagate any more.